# Keras Discriminator Train Function - should concatenate the fake and real?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, data-science, generative-adversarial-network, discriminator

I noticed a few versions of the Discriminator train function.

```
batch_size = 100

# set_trainability
D.trainable = True

# create noise
noise = np.abs(np.random.randn(batch_size,100))

# fake
x_fake = G.predict(noise)
y_fake = np.zeros((batch_size,2))
y_fake[:,0] = 1

# real
x_real = np.array([sample_data_pp(num=100)[0] for i in range(batch_size)])
y_real = np.zeros((batch_size,2))
y_real[:,1] = 1
```

Should I concatenate the `fake and real`? or train them "separately".
Why (if any) this will have a difference?
For example,

```
D.train_on_batch(x_fake,y_fake)
D.train_on_batch(x_real,y_real)
```

or:

```
x_train = np.concatenate((x_fake,x_real))
y_train = np.concatenate((y_fake,y_real))
D.train_on_batch(x_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generative Adversarial Networks are very volatile and it is hard to know what will work without trying it and measuring the results yourself.

That being said, in my experience, separating real and fake samples is a good practice. See  [here](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks) for a reference.

I believe that training with real and fake separately is critical when Batch Normalization (`keras.layers.BatchNormalization()`) is used as the statistics of the batch are differentiated between for real and fake samples.